# Can we use cardView in Relative layout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

I'm using a simple card View in Relative Layout.
Can i use it in Relative Layout ? If yes then How ?

Comment: Um, put it in a `RelativeLayout`. What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: CardView is just a ViewGroup. You can use it like a normal ViewGroup, in any other viewgroup.

Answer (score 2):

If you use CardView inside RelativeLayout like the following :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ....>
        <....>//Imagine a TextView here 
        <....>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

then you will not be able to arrrage the elements inside the cardview in  a right way.

In short imagine CardView as a Holder, you will have to use a layout inside CardView to make it work in a correct way

for example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ....>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <....>//Imagine a TextView here 
            <....>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can Use please follow the code:

```
 <!-- About Panel -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_About"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cv_Help"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/pad_20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="@color/dimblack"
            android:id="@+id/tvAbout"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Cheers!!